# Pourquoi "problème d'yeux" ?

Tags: prononciation, élision, écriture

Pourquoi écrit-on *[problème d'yeux](https://www.docteurclic.com/encyclopedie/problemes-d-yeux.aspx)* et pas *problème de yeux* voire *problème des yeux* ?

Comment prononce-t-on *problème d'yeux* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La question de la règle de l'élision devant les voyelles est une question de phonétique ; la graphie s'adapte à la phonétique. Il est plus facile, tout au moins pour certains, d'éviter deux voyelles consécutives; le problème avec *y* est que si c'est une voyelle graphique, le son qui y correspond (/j/, jod) n'est ni voyelle ni consonne ; la même réalité se retrouve pour *w*. Cela est particulièrement bien reconnu en anglais. Il a été reconnu dans les deux langues que l'on devait traiter *y* comme une consonne pour ce problème euphonique des voyelles juxtaposées et donc on devrait dire « de yeux » ;  on dit donc comme suit ;

- de yaourt, de yoghourt, un problème de yard, une course de yachts, je n'accepte pas de yens, il n'y a pas de yoyos dans ses poches, etc

« Yeux » est une exception, ce qui montre, soit dit en passant, que ce problème de voyelles adjacentes est assez relatif. Comme mentionné dans une autre réponse on dit plutôt « problème aux yeux » mais on aura quand même quelque cas où cette combinaison se trouve, telle que  « une paire d'yeux » et la prononciation est la même que celle de « paire dieu ».

Answer (score 3):

Parce que lorsqu'un article se termine par une voyelle et que le mot qu'il précède commence par une voyelle, on réalise une élision: de devient d'.

On dit donc: d'yeux à la place de de yeux (qui est d'ailleurs incorrect, on devrait indiquer "des yeux" et dans ce cas, comme l'article des se termine par un s, il n'y a pas d'élision).
Néanmoins, problème "des" yeux est grammaticalement correct mais impropre dans l'usage, il faut lui préférer l'article défini "aux": problème aux yeux.

Autres exemples:
 - L'arbre et non le arbre.
 - L'oeil et non le oeil.
Mais la chambre et non l'chambre.

La prononciation est en phonétique la suivante: \jø\ "i eu"

Comment: Je sais pour l'élision. Je vous remercie pour votre réponse. Je pensais que *y* devrait se comporter comme dans le mot yaourt. Idée bête effectivement:-)!

Answer (score 0):

C’est bien « problème d’yeux » et non « - des yeux » car la forme « d’yeux » est indéterminée; or un problème est toujours suivi d’un indéterminé: problème de peau, problème d’eau etc. si on ne sait pas de quel objet ou de quel problème on parle précisément. Et on utilise l’élision ici parce que de est suivi d’un son « eu » donc ce serait pas phonétiquement esthétique de dire « de yeux » [dø.jyø], sans parler de la diphtongue que forme le y avec e et u